# C++11 compatibility of sparse matrix implementations

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, ublas

I try to create a `compressed_matrix` using a `coordinate_matrix` as a builder:

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_sparse.hpp>

using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  coordinate_matrix<int> m1(100, 100, 100);

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    m1.insert_element(i,i,i);

  compressed_matrix<int> m2(m1, 100);
}
```

This seems to work fine using boost 1.54 and clang, but when I compile it using std=c++11, an error is thrown:

```
 choeger@daishi /tmp % clang++ test.cpp --std=c++11
In file included from test.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp:18:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../../include/c++/4.8.2/sstream:38:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../../include/c++/4.8.2/istream:38:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../../include/c++/4.8.2/ios:40:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../../include/c++/4.8.2/bits/char_traits.h:39:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../../include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:147:7: error: no matching function for call to 'swap'
      swap(*__a, *__b);
```

Are there known incompatibilities of boost 1.54 with C++11? Or did I make some C++11 error? The 1.55 [changelog](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_55_0.html) does not mention ublas nor matrices, so I guess it is still present.

This happens both with gcc 4.8.2 and clang 3.4

Comment: [This](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/index-pair-array-and-index-triple-array-on-gcc4-8-c-11-td4661142.html) seems to explain the problem. [Copying one of the workarounds for older compilers in "boost/numeric/ublas/detail/config.hpp" seems to make it compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/381cf2a0735924d8) (although I don't know if it behaves as it should at runtime because I have never used uBLAS and have no idea what you are trying to do). Hope this helps (but don't be surprised if it doesn't).

Comment: Could you make this an answer?

Comment: I don't feel confident giving an answer about something I know so little about. Feel free to add your own answer if you understand the problem/solution (I'll upvote it).

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely a bug in Boost. The problem is that when `BOOST_UBLAS_STRICT_MATRIX_SPARSE` is defined, `coordinate_matrix` and its iterator types use a proxy class as their `reference` type:

```
#ifndef BOOST_UBLAS_STRICT_MATRIX_SPARSE
        typedef T &reference;
#else
        typedef sparse_matrix_element<self_type> reference;
#endif
```

which violates the C++ standard's requirement that the `reference` type for forward iterators is a true reference. C++11 [forward.iterators]/1 states: "A class or pointer type `X` satisfies the requirements of a forward iterator if ... if `X` is a mutable iterator, `reference` is a reference to `T`; if `X` is a `const` iterator, `reference` is a reference to `const T`, ...".

The `coordinate_matrix` iterators claim to be bidirectional iterators despite this fact, resulting in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question:

Thanks to @cv_and_he's comment, I figured the following part of the [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) is relevant here (because `coordinate_matrix` calls `std::sort`):

> Random-access iterators to the initial and final positions of the
>   sequence to be sorted. The range used is [first,last), which contains
>   all the elements between first and last, including the element pointed
>   by first but not the element pointed by last. RandomAccessIterator
>   shall point **to a type for which swap is properly defined** and which is
>   both move-constructible and move-assignable.

Apparently, the swap method is not defined properly (whatever that means).

Bug is reported [here](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10127).